# Excel VBA: how come PasteValues gives Run-time error 1004 in second loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a looping code that calls the below code PasteValue() to generate a tab with values only for each loop/test case. When I run the loop initally, the tab for test1 is generated as desired. But when it moves onto test2, a new tab is created properly but I get the run-time error 1004 while it is trying to paste value (bolded line). Can someone tell the reason for this error? How come it works for the first loop and fails the second time?

```
Private Sub PasteValue()

Dim tabName As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

tabName = Sheets("Main").Range("D5").Value
filePath = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\My Work\test\All Test Results Paste Values.xlsx"

Worksheets("Main").Range("Summary").Select
Worksheets("Main").Range("Summary").Copy

' create workbook if it does not exist
If Dir(filePath) = "" Then
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add().Name = tabName
Else
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=filePath
    If sheetExists(tabName) Then
        Sheets(tabName).Select
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add().Name = tabName
    End If
End If

' paste value and format
With Worksheets(tabName).Range("A1")
    **.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False**
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With

' save workbook
If Dir(filePath) = "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are adding a new *workbook*. Then when you hit your `With` statement, you give the range a worksheet, but not which workbook it's supposed to be on.  You need to add the new workbook to that line.  I'd do something like: `Dim newWB as Workbook // Set newWB = Workbooks.Add // newWB.Sheets.Add().Name = tabName // ... // With newWB.Worksheets(tabName).Range("A1")...`.   But you need to also make sure on the first loop it uses the original workbook, so do same there.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for the help. For the second loop, only a new worksheet should be created. not a workbook. The new workbook is created only in the first loop so I don't believe this is the problem.

Comment: Right before the line giving the error, add `Debug.print ActiveWorkbook.name` when you run it twice (with the first time having it work correctly), is the name shown in the Immediate Window the same for both loops?

Comment: @BruceWayne the name is the same for both loop

Comment: @BruceWayne A pattern I see is that the code is not able to paste in a new worksheet created in a workbook specified in the C: location. It works in the first loop since the workbook is not saved in the C: location yet. Once it is saved to the specific file location, let's say in the second loop, a new worksheet can be created but paste value somehow fails.

Comment: What workbook is `Sheets("Main")` in? (Note I deleted/re-added my answer).  Another workbook altogether?  Can you provide a sample path to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get this working, with fully qualified ranges.  Check it out and see if it works, you might (probably) need to tweak, but let me know if you have any questions.

My main question is what workbook is the `tabName = SheetS("Main")...` in?

```
Private Sub PasteValue()
Dim tabName As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mainWB As Workbook, newWB As Workbook

' What workbook is this on?
Set mainWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ME\Desktop\My Work\test\MAIN WORKBOOK.xlsm")

tabName = mainWB.Sheets("Main").Range("D5").Value

filePath = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\My Work\test\All Test Results Paste Values.xlsx"

' create workbook if it does not exist
If Dir(filePath) = "" Then
    tabName = mainWB.Sheets("Main").Range("D5").Value
    Set mainWB = Workbooks.Add
    mainWB.Sheets.Add().Name = tabName
Else
   Set mainWB = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    If Not SheetExists(tabName) Then
        mainWB.Sheets.Add().Name = tabName
    End If
End If

' paste value and format
With mainWB.Worksheets(tabName).Range("A1")
    mainWB.Worksheets("Main").Range("Summary").Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With

' save workbook
If Dir(filePath) = "" Then
    mainWB.SaveAs Filename:=filePath
Else
    mainWB.Save
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the Main worksheet is in the workbook where the calculations are done and the VBA codes are stored.

Comment: @Fammerjammer - See my edit. I added a line that uses that main workbook.  Again, you might have to tweak/edit that but it should work.